# LWC constructor() error: "Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor"

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, constructor, javascript-debugging

I'm getting the following error:

> Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

after adding a very simple test constructor to my LWC

```
constructor() {
    console.log('constructing');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

### Solution

Add `super()` as the first statement in your constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super(); // this is required
    console.log('constructing');
}
```

---

### Reason

The requirement for a custom element constructor's first statement to be a call to construct the parent class (`LightningElement`) comes from the [HTML: Custom elements spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html) and is referenced in the [LWC Documentation on the constructor() lifecycle hook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_created) which says

> The first statement must be `super()` with no parameters. This call
>   establishes the correct prototype chain and value for `this`.